# how to create a new database after a trigger fired from a table

Tags: sql-server

I got a requirement from client to create a new database when somebody insert new record in a specific table. I want to have all the tables, stored procedure and other things in the new database from the current database.

I am planning to restore the current database with the new Name.

Can anybody tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this seems a pretty strange thing to do, if you really have to then create an Agent job that simply restores the database from a backup. In the trigger, you could run the job with:

```
EXEC msdb..sp_start_job @job_name = 'JobName'
```

I imagine you also need to pass some parameters to that job. You can store those in a table in a database (preferably a central one).

Anyway, I'd be more in favor of creating the database from scripts (schema and data), since it's easier to maintain.